# When do characters get numbered powers from themes? Is this a bug in Character Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I'm running a D&D 4e game and we us the Character Builder exclusively to manage our character sheets & powers. My party members all have themes, and they all just made 2nd level - but their character sheets don't seem to have power cards for their "THEME 2" powers. Here's an excerpt from the Noble character theme[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=860):

> **Noble Starting Feature (1st level):** You gain the noble presence power.
>   **Noble Level 5 Feature (5th level):** You gain one common suit of magic armor, weapon, or neck slot item of 6th level or lower.
>   **Noble Level 10 Feature (10th level):** You gain a +2 power bonus to Diplomacy checks and Insight checks.
>
> Noble Utility - ***Noble Presence*** - You encourage your allies to improve their positions and stand firm against the foe. [...]
>
> Noble Utility 2 - ***Noble Influence*** - If a logical argument or a heartfelt appeal won’t move your adversary, perhaps your exalted title will. [...]

Noble Presence is on the power-cards page at second level, but Noble Influence isn't. This is true for all of my player-themes.

What is the rule to get your "THEME 2" power, if it isn't character level? Or, is this a bug in Character Builder, or do I have to press a button somewhere to refresh their theme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**"Noble Utility 2" equates in function to "$Class Utility 2". It is a utility power of the second level that may be taken whenever you may choose or rechoose a power of the appropriate level.**

However, you do not automatically get utility powers nor encounter powers offered by themes. Instead you may choose to replace your normal powers with theme powers. Unnumbered powers are considered "Class features" and may not be taken as an option save when the class or theme or feat or other feature explicitly indicates that you can.

Comment: Hmm. Not as powerful as I thought. I'll double-check the character builder...

Comment: Yup. There it is on the list of level 2 powers as an option. Thanks for settling the confusion.

Comment: One useful note for others that can't find their Theme powers on character builder: There is a check box "Show Additional Options" that is unchecked, and so suppresses them by default.